# Sails JS actions2 req, res undefined

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have been extracting req and res using this format:

```
fn: async function(inputs, exits, { req, res }) {...}
```

I didn't have any problem until I deleted package-lock.json and tried to reinstall everything. Suddenly I get undefined req and res.
It's weird because when I use an env variable and then extract req and res from it like so:

```
fn: async function(inputs, exits, env) { let {req, res} = env ...}
```

everything works. Can someone enlighten me what caused this issue?

Comment: I do not know what caused your issue, but you should be able to access request and response with `this.req` and `this.res` within your action2 controller without specifying anything at all, right?

Comment: Having the same issue. If the parameters are added to the URL (/user/create?name=Jon) req has the parameter. But of the parameters are defined in the request body then it disappears. Confirmed this also using Postman.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this doc](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/upgrading/to-v-1-0), POST has been replaced by PUT (WHY??!!). Once you use PUT as your http verb, parameters show up in the controller.